# how to pass the $_SESSION['var'] array to jquery and do ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem here, I need all the stuffs inside this `$_SESSION['cart']` thing
and pass it to jQuery to use it in  a php-ajax file, my question is, how to do that?

Here's what I have in mind

```
function myfunc()
{
   //save cart to db of logged user
   $("a.savecart").click(function(){
       //how to assign the $_SESSION['cart'] into a js variable ?
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes/ajax.cart.php",
            data:  //what to put here ?
            success: function(data){
              alert(data);
              location.reload();
            }
         });
         return false;
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo it like below (just example):

```
data: {"cart_id" : <?php echo $_SESSION['cart']; ?>},
```

Or if your `$_SESSION['cart']` is an associative array, you can use `json_encode` function.

```
data: <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart']); ?>,
```

**EDIT:**
For example, if your `$_SESSION['cart']` is an array like below:

```
array(
    'id'  => 111;
    'num' => 222;
    //etc...
)
```

Then in your php ajax part, you could get the data by `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['num']` etc...

Comment: yes it's an associative array..but how will i catch it at the php ajax part ?

Comment: my $_SESSION['cart'] contains a data like this `Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [6] => 1
)
1`

Comment: the keys represents product id, while the value represents quantities..so, how to catch that ?

Comment: @sasori You can try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you get :)

Comment: yep, i did var_dump($_POST) at the php ajax file..and am getting that array I posted/commented here

Answer (score 0):

> I need all the stuffs inside this $_SESSION['cart'] thing and pass it
>   to jquery to use it in a php-ajax file,

If the data you need is in session, then you can send empty ajax call and use $_SESSION['cart']. No need to pass it again.

OR

You can assign the value to a hidden field and use it in jquery as -

```
 data:  $("#session_value").val(),
```

Comment: how to you pass an empty ajax call? just, data:'',  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use json. If you have php > 5.2 on your server you can use json_decode and json_encode functions, see at [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php). In data parameter you can use these trick:

```
data: 'jsondata={"some_key":"' + some_var + '"}'
```

attention you should use double quotes in key and value pair. So when it comes to script you can do that:

```
json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);
```